# PostgreSQL: выборка с разных серверов на один?

Tags: postgresql

Существует ли возможность в PostgreSQL делать выборку с разных серверов-PostgreSQL на один.

Пример:

1. В школах находятся серверы с PostgreSQL.
2. Другой сервер с PostgreSQL находится в управлении образования.

Может ли сервер, находящийся в управлении, сделать выборку на школьных серверах?

Comment: Что значит выборка?

Comment: Сервер управления должен, используя SQL-запросы выбрать определенные поля на школьных серверах, то есть собрать информацию со школ для последующей обработки у себя на сервере.

Answer (score 5):

На самом деле проще всего использовать dblink.

Answer (score 1):

Ну тогда можно написать скрипт который будит ходить по серверам вытягивать данные и перекладывать в другую базу. А так чтобы сам сервер это наврятли .

```
# !/bin/sh###usr="root"hosts="localhost"for hst in $hosts ; doconnect=`mysql -h $hst -u $usr -p -e "use test ; select * from user where user='jonny'";`echo $connecthost2="localhost"qwerty=( $connect )echo ${qwerty[0]} ${qwerty[1]} ${qwerty[2]};mysql -h $host2 -u $usr -p -e "use test2; INSERT INTO test2.users (${qwerty[0]}, ${qwerty[1]}) VALUES ('${qwerty[2]}', '${qwerty[3]}');"done
```

Comment: Можно ли примерно набросать этот скрипт.

Comment: можно сделать без ввода пароля --password= И естественно нужно проверять соединение и пример написан для mysql естественно синтаксис будит отличатся да и чуть не забыл еще наверно надо продумать вариант чтоб данные не вставлялись если они уже есть

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть [доступ](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/sql-createusermapping) до каждого [сервера](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/sql-createserver) бд вы можете на своем сервере настроить [внешние таблицы](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/sql-createforeigntable). При правильно построенном запросе ответ со всех серверов можно будет соединить через [UNION](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/queries-union) и получить выборку. хотя это на порядок медленнее, чем запрос со своего сервера, на мой взгляд это один из самых быстрых путей решения.